# How to reorganize crypto centric portfolio to more balanced approach?

Tags: investing, india, cryptocurrency, portfolio, passive-income

I need advice on reorganizing my portfolio to sustain myself and my dependents until their demise.

I live in India. I am in my mid-20s and have 3-4 dependents. I have my own house (no mortgage), a few vehicles with low maintenance charges, half a million in Crypto (OG, Diamond Hands), around $30K in gold, about $20K in stocks, and some land worth about $30K.

In terms of income, I have a job that pays me around $6K monthly, and half of my crypto portfolio is staked in one way or another, earning me another $1-2K monthly, depending on the price swings. And less than $100 annually through any dividends/interests, etc. I have no debts.

I want a more balanced portfolio with more stocks, bonds, gold, real estate, etc. And have a monthly income of at least $1K (post tax, 30% tax bracket nowadays) for the coming future, even if I quit my job, or there is a crypto winter, or the stock/bond market is down. Around $1K is the maximum I spend a month (including my and my dependent's expenses) on average.

Where I live, having a good financial planner is hard to get, who doesn't get spooked by learning about Crypto, as that is the majority of the portfolio for now. What are good ways of planning that? Any advice/suggestions on how to do it?

Best Case Scenario: Appreciate the assets by 5-10% yearly (on top of inflation).

Realistic (hopefully) Scenario: Appreciate the assets by 1-2% yearly (on top of inflation)

Worst Case Scenario: Beat the inflation at least.

Comment: Does OG mean "original gangster"? Does "OG, Diamond Hands" mean that you have held cryptocurrency since its early days, through all of its ups and downs?

Comment: Since early days, seen a lot of ups and downs.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are doing pretty well. Therefore, my advice would be to use bonds only for a small emergency fund. Maybe you could store one year of all your expenses to your emergency fund, and all of the rest should go to stocks. None should go to cryptocurrencies or real estate.

Generally, real estate has a rather poor rate of return. Maybe you could achieve 1-2% over inflation after taxes, but not much more. Remember that whatever rent income you get, you muse use it to maintain your real estate or else if you don't do that, you will find it deteriorates and your rent income vanishes due to the poor condition of your property. So if someone says you can get 4-5% rental yield, you must deduct the maintenance, the depreciation in value of your property (due to aging), and taxes of course. So that gives about 1-2% over inflation after all expenses.

However, since you are young, and have a salary I'm sure is extraordinarily good in your country, you should be bold and invest into something that yields a lot. Your "best case" scenario is achievable with stocks, but not with any else financial instruments.

Cryptocurrencies and gold have just fluctuations in price, not anything that would have inherent return. One ounce of gold today is one ounce of gold in 100 years, it doesn't grow into anything bigger like a tree would grow. So gold isn't investing, it's speculating. Cryptocurrencies are similar, one bitcoin today is one bitcoin in 100 years ... except if it isn't, if everyone moves away from the power-hungry blockchain to a better blockchain with proof of stake, would you still have anything? Maybe if you are the only operator of the blockchain, you could claim you have one bitcoin, but then that bitcoin wouldn't have any value.

Congratulations on getting a lot of money by speculating on price fluctuations! Now it's time to move to investing and away from speculation.

With your 0.58 million, you should expect to get about 22000 USD annually in dividends (minus taxes). That might sound small, but those dividends grow with economy. So if economic growth is 2% real growth + 2% inflation = 4% nominal growth, in 20 years that 22000 USD has grown to 48200 USD, of course part of that is eaten away by inflation but what you get in 20 years should be equal to 32700 USD today, a very nice growth rate.